# Does orthogonalizing an eigenbasis yield an eigenbasis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a 6x6 real symmetric matrix T, of which I (more precisely, Mathematica) already calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I want to obtain the orthogonal matrix which diagonalises T, to do that i just take the matrix formed with the eigenvectors of T and orthogonalize that using Mathematica's Orthogonalize command, which I assume does something like the Gram-Schmidt process on the initial set of eigenvectors.

I do obtain the right matrix (i.e. I can verify that $P^TTP$ does yield the diagonal matrix I'm looking for), nonetheless, I notice that the orthogonalized "eigenvectors" are not eigenvectors anymore. More precisely, one of the vectors that was previously associated with a 0 eigenvalues now seems to not be an eigenvector at all.

I'm asking this here because I think it is more of a linear algebra problem than a Mathematica one.
Resuming: if I orthogonalize an eigenbasis of a symmetric matrix, the orthogonal vectors are not eigenvectors anymore, why?

Thank you

EDIT---

I tried orthogonalizing the eigenspaces one at the time (I have the eigenvalue $\frac{3}{m}$ with multiplicity one, $\frac{3}{2m}$ with multiplicity two and $0$ with multiplicity three) and it did not solve the problem, here's the code in Mathematica

```
    W = Eigenvectors[T];
R1 = Orthogonalize[{W[[2]], W[[3]]}];
R2 = Orthogonalize[{W[[4]], W[[5]], W[[6]]}];
R = {Normalize[W[[1]]], R1[[1]], R1[[2]], R2[[1]], R2[[2]], 
  R2[[3]]}
P = Transpose[R];
Unprotect[P];
Omega = FullSimplify[Transpose[P].T.P, Assumptions -> m > 0]
T.P[[All, 1]]
T.P[[All, 2]]
T.P[[All, 3]]
T.P[[All, 4]]
T.P[[All, 5]]
T.P[[All, 6]]
```

And the output is

```
{{3/m, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3/(2 m), 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3/(2 m), 0, 0,
   0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

for $P^TTP$, as you can see it is diagonal

and

```
{-(3/(2 m)), -(Sqrt[3]/(2 m)), 3/(
 2 m), -(Sqrt[3]/(2 m)), 0, Sqrt[3]/m}

{3/(4 m), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(3/(4 m)), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), 0, Sqrt[3]/(
 2 m)}

{-(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(3/(4 m)), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), 3/(4 m), Sqrt[3]/(
 2 m), 0}

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

{Sqrt[3/77]/(2 m) - Sqrt[11/21]/(4 m) + 5/(4 Sqrt[231] m), 0, 
 Sqrt[3/77]/(2 m) - Sqrt[11/21]/(4 m) + 5/(
  4 Sqrt[231] m), 0, -(Sqrt[(3/77)]/m) + Sqrt[11/21]/(2 m) - 5/(
  2 Sqrt[231] m), 0}

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

As you can see the fifth vector is wrong, and finally, "true" for the OrthogonalMatrixQ

EDIT 2---

Here's how the matrix $T$ is constructed in the code, it is the Hessian matrix of a potential, that can assure you that it is symmetric

```
V = 1/2*((Norm[a1 - a2] - l)^2 + (Norm[a1 - a3] - 
        l)^2 + (Norm[a2 - a3] - l)^2);
C = D[V, {{x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3}, 2}];
Unprotect[C];
B = C /. {x1 -> 0, y1 -> 0, x2 -> l, y2 -> 0, x3 -> l/2, 
    y3 -> Sqrt[3] l/2};
K = FullSimplify[B, Assumptions -> l > 0];
M = DiagonalMatrix[{1/Sqrt[m], 1/Sqrt[m], 1/Sqrt[m], 1/Sqrt[m], 
    1/Sqrt[m], 1/Sqrt[m]}];
A = M.K.M;
T = FullSimplify[A, Assumptions -> m > 0];
```

and explicitly

```
{{5/(4 m), Sqrt[3]/(4 m), -(1/m), 
  0, -(1/(4 m)), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m))}, {Sqrt[3]/(4 m), 3/(4 m), 0, 
  0, -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(3/(4 m))}, {-(1/m), 0, 5/(
  4 m), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(1/(4 m)), Sqrt[3]/(4 m)}, {0, 
  0, -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), 3/(4 m), Sqrt[3]/(
  4 m), -(3/(4 m))}, {-(1/(4 m)), -(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(1/(4 m)), Sqrt[
  3]/(4 m), 1/(2 m), 0}, {-(Sqrt[3]/(4 m)), -(3/(4 m)), Sqrt[3]/(
  4 m), -(3/(4 m)), 0, 3/(2 m)}}
```

Comment: Just a curiosity: how many eigenvalues 0 do you have? I bet more than one

Comment: If $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $P^TTP$ is diagonal, then the columns of $P$ **must** be eigenvectors of $T$.  What leads you to believe that they "are not eigenvectors anymore"?

Comment: Exodd, you are correct, I have three 0 eigenvalues, Omnomnomnom I can directly verify that for the fifth column of $P$, let us call that $v_5$, $Tv_5$ is not the 0 vector, and the fifth eigenvalue is 0

Comment: A note on notation: I get uncomfortable whenever $T$ is used both as a matrix/transformation and to indicate the transpose in the same context, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: You're right on the notation, that's just what I had called the matrix without thinking about it

Comment: @Chris but is $Tv_5$ a multiple of $v_5$?  If it isn't, then either $P^TTP$ isn't diagonal or $P$ isn't orthogonal.

Comment: It is not, moreover, I start with three eigenvalues 0 and I end up with two, that couldn't be right even if $Tv_5$ was a multiple of $v_5$, nonetheless Mathematica says that my diagonalisation matrix is orthogonal and that $P^TTP$ is diagonal

Comment: Well you might as well include the matrix $T$ in your code listing.

Comment: When I apply `Simplify` to the fifth vector I get `0`.

Comment: Oh God, that was stupid, thank you very much

Comment: Rather than trying to eyeball the results, I would’ve first tried `R.T-DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[T]].R // Simplify` and checked that the result was zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear combination of eigenvectors corresponding to *the same eigenvalue* is still an eigenvector.  But a linear combination of eigenvectors corresponding to *different* eigenvalues is probably not an eigenvector at all.

However, remember that eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix corresponding to different eigenvalues are guaranteed to be orthogonal.  So to find an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, you can:

1. Find an eigenbasis in the usual way.
2. For each eigenvalue of multiplicity one, divide the corresponding eigenvector by its length to make it a unit vector.
3. For each eigenvalue of multiplicity more than one, use Gram-Schmidt on the set of eigenvectors you found corresponding to that eigenvalue.

This gives you an orthonormal basis for each eigenspace, which (since all the eigenspaces are orthogonal) can all be collected to an orthonormal basis of the domain space.

Comment: Right, forgot about that, I have to orthogonalize one eigenspace at the time! I'm gonna try that right away, nevertheless, why as Omnomnom said I have that $P$ is orthogonal, $P^TTP$ is diagonal yet the columns of $P$ aren't eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, I specified how in the edit

Comment: @Chris: I agree with Omnomnom.  Double check your assertion that the columns of $P$ (specifically, the ones associated to repeated eigenvalues) are not eigenvectors.

Comment: The procedure described works for all matrices with an eigendecomposition -- for a symmetric/hermitian, you can just gram-schmidt the whole set of eigenvectors in one shot, since the eigenspaces are orthogonal for different eigenvalues.

Comment: @Batman: You're right; I was being overly cautious.  Gram-Schmidt on the eigenvectors does use a linear combination of eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvectors, but because of the orthogonality, the coefficients corresponding to those different eigenvectors will be zero.

Comment: Err, the last comment was a bit incorrect -- it should say the procedure described produces an orthonormal eigenbasis for each eigenspace. Obviously, the eigenspaces are not goign to be orthogonal in the general case when an eigendecomposition exists. But in the symmetric/hermitian case, both procedures will produce a basis of orthonormal eigenvectors for the whole space (and also for each eigenspace, trivially).